# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') show from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, datatable

I'm getting this error when I try to output data from JSON:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

This is the code I use for fetching data API JSON:

```
<script>
var myArray = []

$.ajax({
        method:'GET',
        url:'https:/*****/api/customer/',
        success:function(response){
            myArray = response.data
            buildTable(myArray)
            console.log(myArray)
        }
    })
    
    function buildTable(data){
        var table = document.getElementById('myTable')

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var row = `<tr>
                            <td>${data[i].nama}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].uid}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].pos}</td>
                      </tr>`
            table.innerHTML += row


        }
    }
</script>
```

This is the JSON form:

```
[
  {
    "nama": "Mei Nurmita Sari, Amd.Keb",
    "uid": "288-028-23072015",
    "pos": "Director",
    "hp": "",
    "fb": "Mei",
    "ig": "meinu",
    "area": "Kalianda Lampung Selatan ",
    "alamat": "Kalianda-lampung selatan"
  },
  {
    "nama": "Rahma Dhania",
    "uid": "288-334-16092017",
    "pos": "Manager",
    "hp": "081297",
    "fb": null,
    "ig": null,
    "area": null,
    "alamat": "Balikpapan"
  },
```

Any insight why I got error in length?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Kindly include how you are fetching the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass your response and process it. It doesn't have `data` property.

Since `response.data` gives `undefined` and we are calling `undefined.length`, it throws an error 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')'

```js
 $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
    success: function(response) {
        buildTable(response)
    }
 })

 function buildTable(data) {
    var table = document.getElementById('myTable')

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var row = `<tr>
                            <td>${data[i].name}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].username}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].address.city}</td>
                      </tr>`
        table.innerHTML += row
    }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable">
</table>
```